# How can the font size be changed in Notepad++?

Tags: windows, fonts, notepad++

How can the font size be changed in Notepad++?

I just downloaded and installed Notepad++ v5.4.5 (I have been using
UltraEdit for the last 11.5 years) and can not find a menu
command for changing the screen font. I want to change it to
Lucida Console 18pt.

---

Other notes: to download Notepad++ go directly to 
the [SourceForce download page for Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/files/).

<sub>(Note: Another question, *[How do I change Notepad++'s console font?](https://superuser.com/questions/198942/how-do-i-change-notepads-console-font)*, deals with changing the font (not the font size). For instance, answers to that question that only talks about font size are being downvoted.)</sub>

Comment: The Notepad++ configurations are all highly non-intuitive.  It's disgusting that "How do I change the font?" in a rich-UI windows text editor needs to be asked and upvoted two-dozen times.

Comment: Agreed. Notepad++ configuration options suck. The max font size there is 28. Why on earth the max is set to 28?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change Notepad++'s console font?](http://superuser.com/questions/198942/how-do-i-change-notepads-console-font)

Comment: @Peter why u edited all my answers? I've a serious disorder while coming to keeping things as I like...If you have any suggestions regarding my answers pls, post in comments...It may sounds rude. But, it's been 2 days since I slept...whenever i see my answers i feel like you are yelling & criticizing about my written communication skills...Sorry if I'm too open.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Open menu Settings/Style Configurator. Then with the *default theme* "Default (stylers.xml)" and *default language* "Global Styles", change the font name and font size for style "Default Style" (the default, style "Global override" will ***not*** cut it).

If a document is already open then the display will change immediately as the font name and font size is changed - nice touch! Press the "Save & Close" button to keep the new settings.

Note that in Notepad++ 6.0, you will also need to check the enable global font and enable global font size check boxes.

Comment: Where are they, *the global font and enable global font size check boxes*?? (I couldn't immmediately find them in Notepad++ 6.6.9.)

Comment: If the styles do not change immediately, note that there is a checkbox to enable global font size changes - for me I hadn't noticed it!

Answer (score 124):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>NUMPAD +</kbd>/<kbd>NUMPAD -</kbd> or mouse wheel to zoom in/out

Edit: Or to achieve exactly what you asked for...

Settings > Style Configurator. Under Font Style you can set the font and size

Comment: Zoom level is not the same as font size. For instance, when printing it is the font size that matters, not the zoom level.

Answer (score 33):

[image]

Alternatively, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and use the scroll wheel of your mouse.

Comment: How can this change the font to "Lucida Console"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Try http://superuser.com/a/198948/78897

Comment: Zoom level is not the same as font size. For instance, when printing it is the font size that matters, not the zoom level.

Answer (score 21):

Menu *Settings* -> *Style Configurator* ->

*Font Style*:

```
Font Name
Font Size
```

Then check:

1. Enable global font
2. Enable global font size

Then click on "Save & Close" button.

[image]

Comment: In [my answer](http://superuser.com/questions/16831/how-can-the-font-size-be-changed-in-notepad/123826#123826) I stated it did ***not*** work for Style = "Global override" (it should be "Default Style" instead - the second option). Which version of Notepad++ did you use for testing?

Answer (score 3):

Fonts and styles can be changed in the Style Configurator.

- Settings
- Style Configurator

Answer (score 3):

With 5.9.4 I have found that the global override does cut it, as zooming seems to influence global and language-specific font settings differently so that whitespace has different sizes (Tabs don't line up with different zoom levels). The font size did not seem to change either..

Comment: So... is this a fix to the problem or..?

Answer (score 3):

*(Notepad++ 6.1.1)*

I'm not sure about you, but to me this feature should be in **Preferences**. I totally missed it when it was right underneath it :p.

Anyway, you could kill two birds with one stone by changing the theme.

**Change font & Chose a dark background:**

1. Go to *Settings* on the top menu
2. Chose *Style Configurator...*
3. At the top it's the theme selector *Select theme*

Notepad++ has many themes to choose from, so if you're one of those that likes to code on a dark background with a san-serif font the *Ruby Blue* theme is a good choice, it works great for me.

My 2¢.

Answer (score 3):

There's a much easier way to change the font by using Notepad++ itself. Go to:
**"C:\Users[your username]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\stylers.xml"** and open it. Then copy the string fontName="", press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and on the first field what you need to be found paste the copied string. On the second field (this tells you what you want to replace the copied string with), enter `fontName="Calibri"` (or another font you like), click "replace everything" and DON'T FORGET TO TICK THE TICKBOX TO SEARCH ONLY FOR WHOLE WORDS BEFORE DOING ALL THAT.

After that, find the string `fontSize=""` and replace it with `fontSize="11"` (or any other size you prefer. Then save the file and restart NPP. This is how I did it, and here's the result:

[image: Screenshot of the changed file, 'stylers.xml']

Font: Calibri (my favourite font), font size: 11 (my favourite size for Calibri). **Then archive the entire "C:\Users[your username]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\" to another drive (not on C:), so the next time you need to reinstall the OS, you'd be able to restore your settings on fonts.**

This might sound oldschool to some people, but I'm an oldschool myself and this is the way I prefer to do it instead of relying on the program's options.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll the mouse wheel up while pressing Ctrl...

Comment: This changes the display size but doesn't actually sent a typeface or font size in the document.

Comment: Zoom level is not the same as font size. For instance, when printing it is the font size that matters, not the zoom level.